# why pip is not installed but after creating new venv and activating it, pip does work?

Tags: environment-variables, pip, virtualenv

I'm confused by venv in linux.
I have a fresh ubuntu 20.04 installed. when I entered `python` in terminal it says *command python is not found* and the same for `pip`, but `python3` works (still not for pip or pip3).
I created a venv using `python3 -m venv new_env` and `python` command works there and its version is 3 but this time pip runs with no problem.
My question is why this happens and how to make `python` command runs `python3` in main environment as well. Is it related to environment variables and PATH and causes problem when working with different venvs?

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 [is finishing its life cycle](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/), that's why it's [not getting installed by default in Ubuntu](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-20.04-Clear-Python2). You can use pip for python3 using pip3, same as with the usual pip command:

```
pip3 install -U numpy #example
```

As for which python/pip version is being used whenever you run a command, the `which` command is useful:

```
which pip3
```

Returns:

/home/guille/.local/bin/pip3

In my case. When creating a virtual environment, the `pip` command is referencing the pip3 executable you have created in the environment, so that `which pip` is actually a shortcut to the created pip3 executable in the virtual environment, returning:

```
/home/you/locationOfVenv/NameOfVenvThatWorksWithPython3/bin/pip
```

Comment: pip is not installed in main env, but when create new venv it is installed there!